# Entity Framework Query Optimization

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've got a couple of months experience working with Entity Framework and mostly writing a ton of data retrieval linq queries against it.  I come from a heavy sql background, and am trying to optimize some of the sql for performance and readability if I'm trying to debug performance issues.

I am noticing some of the generated sql does things like this for a tableA with columns {col1,col2,col3}

```
select
    Extent1.col1
from
(
   select col1, col2, col3 from tableA
) AS Extent1
```

My question is, how do I prevent it from doing these useless derived tables, and instead just do

```
select col1 from tableA
```

where it is needed?  I can't seem to figure out why it sometimes does this and other times it doesn't...

Comment: I'm interested in hearing other people's thoughts; but I think this is just one of the draw backs of using EF (as well as other ORM's?).  You lose a lot of control over the actual SQL that is generated, and the generated SQL is often pretty bad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Improve query generated from entity framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418675/improve-query-generated-from-entity-framework)

Answer (score 5):

Have you compared the actual query execution plans of the generated query against how you would optimize it? You might be surprised at the results, I know I was. And I gained a deep respect for the devs on the SQL server team who seem to be doing quite an excellent job at making what looks like a sub-optimal query perform just the same.

I'd be interested in hearing if your experience differs from mine; I stopped looking for ways to change the generated queries because for every query I tried looking at, there was no real difference in performance.

**EDIT:**
My last statement isn't entirely true, there are definitely N+1 situations that you have to watch out for, and any batch operations (updates, deletes, and inserts of multiple records at the same time) aren't going to be even close in performance to writing a query by hand due to the nature of working with individual records. But the extraneous extents essentially get stripped out by the SQL Server query optimizer.

Comment: Hi Joel, in general you are correct, but I have a couple real nasty queries that are about 300 lines long that do this "useless derived tables" business multiple times throughout.  Taking that query and simply replacing the derived tables with their subsequent direct select from the table counterpart takes a huge query like that from 7 seconds down to sub 1 seconds.... so I agree with you for the most part, but trying to figure out how I can better optimize my linq so that I don't run into this issue.

Comment: @Isamu: Generally if you can make your LINQ query simpler, the SQL gets simpler too. There are a lot of techniques for doing this, but without any code to look at in the first place, it's difficult to give specific advice. Is the >7x performance gain you're reporting as a direct result of removing the unnecessary columns from the EF-generated code, or are you doing more complex transformations?

Comment: I'm assuming you accounted for query caching when you tested the performance difference... There is a blog post on the EF team blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/07/25/generated-sql-improvements-for-tpt-queries.aspx) that's open for feedback on specific issues related to performance improvements for generated SQL. That specific post talks about the improvements they've made when dealing with a table-per-type class inheritance hierarchy in the most recent release.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I'm doing nothing complicated, just removing what I've described in my initial question from the 4 or 5 spots in the query.

Comment: @Zom: Joel C makes a good point about query caching. It may be that you're suffering from a bad cached query due to parameter sniffing, and changing the SQL is only a temporary solution. What happens if you only remove a single column name from the extent (thereby changing the query just enough to avoid caching the execution plan)? PS--If you want to add code, edit your question and put it there.